# Read More button appearing for text that is not truncated

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Read More button that when clicked shows the rest of the truncated text, the code is working but my problem is that the button also appears for text that is not truncated. How can I make it to appear only for truncated texts.

My code:

HTML:

```
<p><strong>Overview:</strong>
      <span class="overview">{{ game.overview|default:"N/A"|truncatewords_html:"50" }}</span>
      {% if game.overview|length > 50 %}
      <span class="full-text" style="display: none;">{{ game.overview|default:"N/A" }}</span>
      <button class="read-button" onclick="readMore(this)">[Read more...]</button>
      {% endif %}
    </p>
```

JS:

```
function readMore(button) {
    var parent = button.parentNode;
    var truncatedText = parent.querySelector(".overview");
    var fullText = parent.querySelector(".full-text");

    if (fullText.style.display === "none" || fullText.style.display === "") {
      truncatedText.style.display = "none";
      fullText.style.display = "inline";
      button.innerHTML = "[Read less...]";
    } else {
      truncatedText.style.display = "inline";
      fullText.style.display = "none";
      button.innerHTML = "[Read more...]";
    }
  }
```

Comment: `truncatewords_html:"50"` "ignores" any HTML tags you have in that content, the limit of `50` is applied to the actual text content. `{% if game.overview|length > 50 %}` however checks the length of the content _including_ any tags. So you are comparing apples with oranges here.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what am I supposed to do? I tried '{% if game.overview|striptags|length > 50 %}' but it is the same.

Comment: `game.overview|truncatewords_html:"50"|length > 50` ...?